# Why does not out-of bound access to an allocatable array cause an error?

Tags: fortran, dynamic-allocation

I do not understand why this code does not produce any segmentation fault. I was expecting some errors while compiling the code or in run-time, but it runs apparently correctly.

```
program alloc

implicit none

real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: myVec

allocate(myVec(3,2))    

myVec=1.

myVec(100,3)=10.

write(*,*) myVec(1,1)

return
end
```

Could somebody shed some light on this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

With `gfortran`, you can use the `-fbounds-check` compiler flag (or `-C` with `ifort`) in order to look for this kind of errors. When you compile your example with this option, the program produces:

```
Fortran runtime error: Index '3' of dimension 2 of array 'myvec' above upper bound of 2
```

As to why the program does not crash immediately, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452959/why-doesnt-my-program-crash-when-i-write-past-the-end-of-an-array) contains more details.

Comment: Thank you very much, is it the same with mpifort?

Comment: mpifort is just a wrapper around a compiler, it is the same