# Proper way to fill a flexible array of strings inside of a struct?

Tags: c

I have a problem with filling a flexible array of strings (`char *`) inside of a simple struct (the story is, I want to store a message as a string and a list of Redis lists names to send that message to in a struct, to publish to Redis later when a certain callback is called). The array has to be flexible because the number of Redis lists can vary based on a configuration file given to the program.

I can't seem to fill my array properly, I am expecting an array of size 2 in my case and no matter how much memory I allocate, gdb tells me it is of size 1 (I can only see the element of index 0 in the CLion Debugger panel). Two things trouble me :

- It seems like I can assign values to indexes beyond what I intended when allocating memory,
- even worse, I can access memory through elements of the array beyond the supposed array size.

I've seen examples of Flexible Array Members in `struct`s but couldn't find an example with FAMs of `char *`. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here ? Here is an example below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    const char *redis_message;
    const char *redis_lists[];
} redis_data;

int main() {
    size_t num_lists = 2;
    const char *example_redis_lists[num_lists];

    // strings with different lengths
    example_redis_lists[0] = "foo_bar";
    example_redis_lists[1] = "bar";

    // this should initialize the struct with an array of size num_lists, right ?
    redis_data *data = malloc(sizeof(redis_data) + num_lists * sizeof(char *));
    data->redis_message = "Hello World !";

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < num_lists; idx ++) {
        const char *string = example_redis_lists[idx];
        data->redis_lists[idx] = string;
    }

    data->redis_lists[2] = "baz_foobar"; // why can I do this ?
    data->redis_lists[3] = "i am not supposed to be here";
    data->redis_lists[4] = "me neither";

    size_t idx = 0;
    while (data->redis_lists[idx]) {
        // this segfaults if I don't add at least one element past index 1
        fprintf(stderr, "index : %zu, value : %s\n", idx, data->redis_lists[idx]);
        ++idx;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit** : to clarify, in my actual program the redis lists are indeed present in the array (despite gdb not showing them), but when I iterate it with `size_t i= 0; while (data->redis_lists[i]) { send(); ++i; }` I get a segfault because `i` equals the length of the array, and it bothers me to add elements to an array which size should be fixed at runtime.

Comment: The debugger won't know how long it is because it is flexible. It's like when you `malloc` a block of `int`s - the debugger doesn't know how many `int`s will fit in the block.

Comment: You might want to [read the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452959/). The C language doesn't do bounds checking for any array, flexible or otherwise. It's up to you to stay within the bounds of the array.

Comment: Since `redis_data` does not contain anything to indicate the length of the flexible array, you need to record that somewhere. Some options are: (1) store the length externally in some auxiliary variable; (2) add a member to `redis_data` to store the length; or (3) terminate the array contents with a null pointer element to mark the end.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I was able to solve my problem with @IanAbbott 's approach of storing the array length in the struct which seems like the natural solution when, indeed, you can't check your array's bounds in C (thanks for the link !).